# PySpeech Setup on Python 2.7

Tags: python, module, installation, pywin32

I've been thinking about installing the PySpeech module, but I'm not sure if it will work with Python 2.7.6. Also, I heard it needs PyWin32. Where would I get that, and how exactly do I install the modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here (build 218)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/) you can download pywin32. A simpe google search shows the page. [alternative](https://www.dropbox.com/s/27ehvrwv8o5r7qy/Python%20for%20Windows%20extensions%20-%20Browse%20_pywin32_Build%20218%20at%20SourceForge.net.htm)

If you are not sure whether it works then try it out. This is the only possibility to make sure that it works under your specific circumstances. Usually everyone makes everything work with Python 2.7 these days. But this does not include old packages.

[Once you installed pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) you can use `pip install`.

[Have a look at the speech page.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/speech/0.5.1) Try it out and report back.

Comment: Pywin32 straight-up failed. It said Python 2.7 was not installed. It's prompting me for the install directory, I'll backup and give it that...

Comment: Re-installing Python is also no problem. It does not hurt in any way.

Comment: Also, what does Pip have to do with it? On another note, could PySpeech work without Pywin?

Comment: The installed modules are in a folder of Python2.4 and you must put them in the same folder of python2.7.